# How to get original event when trigger

Tags: jquery, events

Is it possible to get the original event object when you trigger it.

In my application I need to trigger the `mousedown` click for some reasons. I need original event to define if the right mouse button was pressed.

```
var app = $("#app");    

$("#something").on("mousedown", function(e){
   app.trigger("somethingClicked", [{data: somedata}])
})


app.on("somethingClicked", function(event, data){
   if (event.which == 3) {
     // right mouse click
   }
   else{
     // left mouse click
   }
});
```

event.which is undefined

**UPDATE**

I have made a research and the best option I've found for myself is to create a new event and trigger it.

```
$("#something").on("mousedown", function(e){
   var somethingClickedEvent = $.Event('somethingClicked', $.extend(e, { type: 'somethingClicked'}));
   app.trigger(somethingClickedEvent, [{data: somedata}])
})
```

Comment: @naathon no, it won't, because in this case `data` becomes `event`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You can simply pass the `which`-property as second argument to `.trigger()` (without need for wrapping it in an object or array) and also receive it in the `somethingClicked`-callback as second argument:

```
$("#something").on("mousedown", function (e) {
    app.trigger("somethingClicked", e.which);
})

$("#app").on("somethingClicked", function (e, w) {
    if (w == 3) console.log("right");
    else if (w == 1) console.log("left");
    else console.log("center");
});
```

Somewhere I have read that `event.which` will become deprecated. You can get the mousebutton in your mousedown function also this way (the numbers are different here!):

```
var button = e.originalEvent.button; // 0 is left, 1 is center, 2 is right
```

2) Another way is to reuse the mousedown-event object (possible with jQuery- but not with native js-events):

```
$("#something").on("mousedown", function (e) {
    e.type = "somethingClicked"; // change event type
    app.trigger(e);
})

$("#app").on("somethingClicked", function (e) {
    // here is the complete mousedown-event object available,
    // only the type has changed to "somethingClicked"
    if (e.which == 3) console.log("right");
    else if (e.which == 1) console.log("left");
    else console.log("center");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The event you trigger sends by default a parameter `e` as the event that's triggered. Therefor, you need to set some additional parameters which can include the original event as well. There's no need to name the additional parameters. You can do this like so:

```
var app = $("#app");

$("#something").on("mousedown", function (e) {
    app.trigger("somethingClicked", [e, "some data"]);
})

app.on("somethingClicked", function (e, event, data) {
    console.log(data);
    if (event.which == 3) {
        console.log("right");
    } else {
        console.log("left");
    }
});
```

See this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZiNNED/hp5ks0ja/) for a working example.

Comment: This won't work since the first `argument` is event. This solution is obvious, but I believe that this is not the best option.